# Issue with expo-updates package: Updates not being applied to the app

Tags: expo, expo-updates

I need help with the `expo-updates` package as it's not updating my app.

I'm calling the `checkForUpdates` function on mount, and initially, it behaves as expected.

However, the function should throw an error at `!result.isNew` after the update, but it doesn't. I added a console log to check the updateId, and it remains the same, indicating that the update is not being applied.

Here's the code snippet:

```
async function checkForUpdates() {
  console.log("Updates.updateId", Updates.updateId); // not changing

  const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();
  if (!update.isAvailable) throw new Error('No updates available');

  const result = await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync();
  if (!result.isNew) throw new Error('Fetched update is not new');

  return true;
}
```

I'm using `Expo SDK version 49.0.0` and `"expo-updates": "~0.18.16"`.

I found a similar issue on GitHub at https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20847, but it seems to involve a conflict with Constants.manifest, which I'm not using in my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to debug the issue by reading the `readLogEntriesAsync` function, and an error message stating `rctErrorDomain could not get batchedBridge` is encountered.

To resolve this, I made a fix by changing the `jsEngine` to `jsc` in the `app.json` file.